# Output object name other than React with jsx syntax

Tags: reactjs

with React v0.12 the @jsx pragma is gone which means it is no longer possible to output jsx with anything other than the React.METHODNAME syntax.

For my use case I am trying to wrap the React object in another object to provide some convenience methods thus, in my component files, I want to be able to write:

```
var myConvenienceObject = require('React-Wrapper');
var Component = myConvenienceObject.createSpecializedClass({
  render: function () {
    return <div />
  }
})
```

However the jsx compiler automatially converts `<div />` into `React.createElement("div", null)`

With older versions of `React` it was possible to handle this using the pragma at the top of the file.  However, since that has been removed, I was wondering if there was any way currently to change the name of the object compiled by jsx so `<div />` would be transformed into `myConvenienceObject.createElement("div", null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's no longer possible to use a custom prefix for JSX.  If you need to do this, you'll need to modify the JSX transform code, or create a fake React.

```
var React = require('react'), FakeReact = Object.assign({}, React, {
    createElement: function(component, props, ...children){
        // ...

        // eventually call the real one
        return React.createElement(component, props, ...children);
    }
});
module.exports = FakeReact;
```

And then to use it you import the fake react and call it React.

```
var React = require('fake-react');

// ...
    render: function(){ return <div />; }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the info!  I guess people will just need to remember to require in `React`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make some elements contains in your `myConvenienceObject`, you could consider the `children` props as shown in the [doc](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html). But this may need some changes in the `myConvenienceObject` too, to accept the children.

By the way, i'm not sure where is this `createSpecializedClass` functions comes from and what it does

Comment: sorry I wasn't more clear about it `createSpecializedClass` is just an example of a wrapper around the standard `React.createClass` method.  Unfortunately, I don't think your recommendation will work in this case because I still wouldn't be able to use jsx in the component file itself.

Comment: would be great if you could paste some code snippet here. The children prop can be the jsx as well, not limited to string